# android progressBar inverse direction programmatically

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have progressBar in my App that is repeatedly showing countdown time from full to zero. After user reaction countdown starts again and progress appears "full" again and it starts shrinking again.

What I want to do is to add animation to "fill up" progressBar with quick animation by users onClick (programmatically), and then start to shrink again. This is my standard code for animation progressBar:

```
 animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 500, 0).setDuration(2500);
```

I have somehow put another animation when user clicks what he is supposed to click, but how to merge that two animations in one concise, sequential  movement?

Answer (score 1):

Use android:layoutDirection="rtl" in progress bar , right to left like :

```
`<ProgressBar
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:max="100"
   android:layout_margin="4dp"
   android:layoutDirection="rtl"
   android:progress="60" />`
```

Comment: my progress bar needs to switch between those directions, that's why I wrote programmatically in title

Comment: try this 
      `ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(findViewById(R.id.progressBar), 
       ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);`

Comment: and how to bind that two directions in one movement